# Constructing an Binary Tree in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement binary tree in java
Here is my code for my binary tree implementation.I am gettng an error please help:

Here it go

```
public static class Binarytree{
        Node root;
        public Binarytree(){

        }
        public void addnode(int data){
            Node newnode = new Node(data);
            if(root==null)
                root = newnode;
            else
            {
                Node coming = root;
                while(true){
                    if(data<coming.data)
                    {   coming = coming.left;
                    if(coming==null)
                    {   coming.left = newnode;
                        return;
                    }
                    }
                    else{
                        coming = coming.right;
                        if(coming==null)
                        {   coming.right = newnode; // Error
                           return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public static class Node{
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right=null;

        Node(int data){
        this.data = data;}
    }

    public  static void main(String[] args) {


           Binarytree so = new Binarytree();
           so.addnode(2);
           so.addnode(42);  // Error
           so.addnode(22);
           so.addnode(12);
           so.addnode(21);
           so.addnode(20);
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

in line `coming.right =  newnode;`
I don't know what's wrong. 
Please Help

Comment: `coming` is null. You only execute that line if `coming` is null, and trying to access a property of a null object is going to cause problems

Comment: If `coming` is null (you've checked that) then you can't access a property of this variable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this block of code:

```
if(coming == null)
{
    coming.right = newnode;
    return;
}
```

If the object reference `coming` is `null`, then you cannot refer to `coming.right` because a `null` reference does not point to an actual object. And without an actual object, you cannot refer to an object field such as `right`. If you try to do something with a reference (or pointer) which is `null` then Java will throw a `NullPointerException` as you see in your case.

What you need to do is to create an actual `Node` object and assign it to the reference `coming` and then you will be able to refer to the field `right` of that object with `coming .right`.

Note that you will have exactly the same error thrown by the first block which begins `if(coming == null)` because it tries to refer to `coming.left` when `coming` is `null`.